# Can we use spring boot 1.4.1 testing framework with java 1.7?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test-mvc

I am using spring boot 1.4.1 on java 1.7. I have a sample controller with one get endpoint "show"

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = SomeController.class)
public class SomeControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void showPage() throws Exception {
        mockMvc
                .perform(get("/show"))
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Some Result")));
    }

 }
```

Below is the error I get when I try to execute my test.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mockMvcWebClientBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/MockMvcWebClientAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.test.web.servlet.htmlunit.MockMvcWebClientBuilder]: Factory method 'mockMvcWebClientBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/Session, offset=6
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
```

A closer look shows the cause is

```
   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.test.web.servlet.htmlunit.MockMvcWebClientBuilder]: Factory method 'mockMvcWebClientBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/Session, offset=6
```

Could some one tell me if it is possible to test with java 1.7 or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot 1.4.1 includes Jetty 9.3 ([see spring-boot-dependencies pom.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1.4.x/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml))

[Their documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_servlet_containers) says Jetty 9.3 requires Java 8+. You should replace it with Jetty 9.2 by redefining the property in your pom:

```
<properties>
    <jetty.version>9.2.19.v20160908</jetty.version>
</properties>
```

---

This happens to be Spring's exact recommandation ([in their documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-jetty-9.2-maven)):

> #### Use Jetty 9.2 with Maven
>
> If you are using the starters and parent you can just add the Jetty
>   starter and override the jetty.version property:
>
> ```
> <properties>
>     <jetty.version>9.2.17.v20160517</jetty.version>
> </properties>
> <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
>         <exclusions>
>             <exclusion>
>                 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>                 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
>             </exclusion>
>         </exclusions>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
> </dependencies>
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alex, out of curiosity is it possible  to use tomcat instead of jetty ?

Comment: of course. Tomcat is used by default and supports java 1.7. Technically, if you remove the spring-boot-starter-jetty dependency + NOT exclude tomcat, you'll be using tomcat (just make sure you don't have other jetty dependencies. You could also ask another question, post your pom and ask how you could use tomcat instead.  I answered with a jetty solution because your stacktrace contained "org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/Session"